# Can't install libgl1-mesa-dri

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 19.04

[image]

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 colord : Depends: libsane (>= 1.0.24)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Link to main problem
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17pBH9FAy49m9JyvMc7_hHZR8XjP4S5yT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: All supported releases of Ubuntu provided `libsane` of at least 1.0.25 (excluding off-topic ESM releases).  Your issue is your release is EOL, it's upgrade path also gone as it *release-upgraded* to 19.10, which itself is EOL thus intended upgrade path is now gone.

Comment: I tried to update but it says following pakage is kept back, neither I can upgrade to ubutu 20.04

Comment: You don't mention trying to upgrade to 20.04, however given 19.04 upgraded to 19.10, which then upgraded to 20.04, you've missed the intended path.  LTS releases have two upgrade paths, all releases (18.04->18.10->19.04->19.10->20.04) or from one LTS to the next LTS (ie. 18.04->20.04) but you used a non-LTS thus selected the *every-release* cycle.  A *upgrade via re-install* is your next best choice in my opinion.  You haven't said if desktop or server, it's can be done without data or settings loss on desktop (just don't format any partitions, it'll only erase system directories)

Comment: Yes, I have to follow the path. Is there any way I can update succesfully to 19.10 and install missing package. I needed it for my project I am attaching a screenshot if you can help me with that. And I am on a system dual booted with win10.

Comment: The Ubuntu upgrade tools won't upgrade you to a release that is EOL (*end-of-life*) so upgrades would need to be manually done.  Ubuntu tools ensure certain packages are upgraded in a specific order, screensaver is disabled during upgrade & other things... which is different to a Debian system where those won't cause an upgrade to fail... Blog sites will tell you how to upgrade debian style, but be aware if may fail - and you're now off-topic as 19.10 is EOL; the supported upgrade path is *upgrade via re-install* (ie. something-else, existing partitions & no-format...)

Comment: The *upgrade via re-install* I mention causes your packages to be noted, system directories erased, new system installed, prior additional packages are re-added to your system (assuming they're available on new release in Ubuntu repositories) without touching user data unless format was selected. As only system directories were wiped, only server apps will lose their configs... but you should still backup regardless.

Comment: Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months as required by non-LTS releases.

Comment: Maybe also useful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading  (Can I skip over releases when upgrading)

Comment: no upgrading is not a problem, I'm going with it I have 20.04 iso file, can you guide on instalation, last time my university teacher helped but now the due to corona I can't go to him. Any video link on this?

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview   Use *something-else*, select your existing partition(s) & ensure *format* checkbox is **not** ticked (this causes the *upgrade via re-install* to be performed instead of clean install).   Backup first as *format* checkbox can be missed; if format is selected all data is erased & new system is installed.

Comment: FYI:   how to install 20.04 or how to upgrade to 20.04 is a new question, and IS on-topic for this site.. Your question about EOL release & upgrade (to 19.10/EOL release) was not.